# How to mirror iPad display to PC to record

Tags: ios, ipad, airplay, screen-recording

I need to put my iPad display onto my PC. By this I mean record or stream iPad footage on software such as OBS or Streamlabs. I have tried several methods such as LonelyScreen, Mirroring360, and even iTools. However none of these have worked so far. I am able to link the iPad to the PC via USB-C cable, so maybe that could be of use.

I am aware this question has been asked, but it has never been answered well. Also, Youtubers have been able to record iOS footage with OBS, I don't know how. Lastly, I have a piece of hardware that is supposed to record Nintendo switch footage through HDMI, and there are maybe other ports to use for iOS USB c type cable input to OBS. I say maybe because I lost the hardware somewhere in my house, so tell me if I should just go for a hunt to go find it.

Comment: Update: Good news! I found the recording hardware. Bad news! it requires HDMI input. I only have USB-C to USB-C. So I need USB-C to HDMI, unless there is another option that doesn't need that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that device was the way to go. They are called Capture Cards, and they use wires not internet servers, which is what I needed. So I just had to go from USB-C to HDMI, through the Capture Card, which then turned it into USB3.0, which finally went into my computer which could pick up video and audio in OBS. Simple enough to set up, and works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [AirServer?](https://www.airserver.com/WindowsDesktop) They're pretty reliable IIRC and only costs $20. Here's a feature list (it does Airplay obviously): https://www.airserver.com/Compare

Comment: I would try AirServer but money is sadly not an option (for reasons) and I need next to no lag time between iPad to OBS, because time is essential for the apps I am trying to record. AirServer is a good option if you don't have a USB cable to connect the two devices though. Thank you!